# Is it possible to set a role specific value for "allow_insecure_uploads?"

Tags: 8, users, configuration

I want to override the value for "allow_insecure_uploads" which is in system.file config, but only for specific roles. Am I going to need to do this in a module / does one already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Module suggestions are usually frowned upon on DA, but regardless the answer is yes; role-specific config values are possible via the D8 config override system.

The Drupal 8 docs has a section on the [config override system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system) with a relevant example in the **Providing overrides from modules** section. After you've declared the override class in your module's `.services.yml` & created the override PHP class, you'll do something like this in the `loadOverrides()` method:

```
 public function loadOverrides($names) {
    $overrides = array();
    // @TODO: define a hasRole($role) class method that checks Drupal::currentUser() for a given role
    $has_role = $this->hasRole('my_role');
    if (in_array('system.file', $names) && $has_role) {
      $overrides['system.file'] = ['allow_insecure_uploads' => TRUE];
    }
    return $overrides;
 }
```